# PostgreSQL: Check if each item in array is contained by a larger string

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-like

I have an array of strings in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT ARRAY['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'];
```

And I have a large paragraph:

```
Dogs and cats have a range of interactions. The natural instincts of each species lead towards antagonistic interactions, though individual animals can have non-aggressive relationships with each other, particularly under conditions where humans have socialized non-aggressive behaviors.

The generally aggressive interactions between the species have been noted in cultural expressions.
```

For each item in the array, I want to check if it appears in my large paragraph string.  I know for any one string, I could do the following:

```
SELECT paragraph_text ILIKE '%dog%';
```

But is there a way to simultaneously check every string in the array (for an arbitrary number of array elements) without resorting to plpgsql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you want something like this (assuming `paragraph_text` is column from table named `table`):

```
SELECT
    paragraph_text,
    sub.word,
    paragraph_text ILIKE '%' || sub.word || '%' as is_word_in_text
FROM
    table1 CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT unnest(ARRAY['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']) as word
    ) as sub;
```

Function `unnest(array)` takes creates table of record from array values. The you can do `CROSS JOIN` which means all rows from `table1` are combines with all rows from that unnest-table.

If `paragraph_text` is some kind of static value (not from table) you can do just:

```
SELECT
    paragraph_text,
    sub.word,
    paragraph_text ILIKE '%' || sub.word || '%' as is_word_in_text
FROM (
         SELECT unnest(ARRAY['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']) as word
     ) as sub;
```

Comment: Thanks--`CROSS JOIN` was a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work only for postgres 8.4 and above as unrest is not available for earlier versions.

```
drop table if exists t;
create temp table t (col1 text, search_terms text[] );
insert into t values
   ('postgress is awesome', array['postgres', 'is', 'bad']), 
   ('i like open source', array['open', 'code', 'i']), 
   ('sql is easy', array['mysql']);

drop table if exists t1;
select *, unnest(search_terms) as search_term into temp t1 from t;

-- depending on how you like to do pattern matching. 
-- it will look for term not whole words
select *, position(search_term in col1) from t1;


-- This will match only whole words.
select *, string_to_array(col1, E' ')@>string_to_array(search_term, E' ') from t1;
```

Basically, you need to flatten array of search_terms into one column and then match long string with each search term row wise.